# Delete specific content in a json file

Tags: python, json

I have this json file :

```
{
    "help": [
        {
            "title": "",
            "date": "",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "",
            "date": "",
            "link": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "",
            "date": "",
            "link": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am currently struggling trying to delete each 'block' in the help list.
I eventually came up with this:

```
import json

with open('dest_file.json', 'w') as dest_file:
    with open('source.json', 'r') as source_file:
        for line in source_file:
            element = json.loads(line.strip())
            if 'help' in element:
                del element['help']
            dest_file.write(json.dumps(element))
```

So I was wondering how could I delete each thing in the help list, without deleting the help list.
ty

Comment: set it to `empty` list instead of deleting it from the dict. Replace `del element['help']` with `element['help'] = []`

Comment: When I try this, I get this:
```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)```

Comment: you have further issues in your script, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can replace the element with an empty list:

```py
if 'help' in element:
    element['help'] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some further issues in the script specifically with line `for line in source_file`. If you read line by line then you are getting each line and not the complete dictionary object and that is giving several other json errors.

Try this:

```
import json

with open('dest_file.json', 'w') as dest_file:
    with open('source.json', 'r') as source_file:
        element = json.load(source_file)
        if "help" in element:
            element['help'] = []
            dest_file.write(json.dumps(element))
```

This works for the above example shown but if you have multiple nested items, then you need to iterate over each separately and fix them individually.